# Angularjs random page scroll issue in Chrome, page scroll not appearing properly during page navigation

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, scroll

In Chrome, default page scroll sometimes show and sometimes not during the page navigation in the angularjs. Chrome version is "Version 52.0.2743.116 m".

I Googled on it and found that one of the old version of Chrome had this issue and in later version it was resolved.

Any helps will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that it might be an issue with your app performance while loading pages.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea to confirm it is due to loading of pages.